# how to sort a list in python consisting of monitor resolutions?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort this list but couldn't find a way to do it.

i/p :

```
['1152x864', '1920x1080', '1600x900', '1280x1024', '1024x768', '640x480', '720x400', '800x600']
```

o/p :

```
['1920x1080', '1600x900', '1280x1024', '1152x864', '1024x768', '800x600', '720x400', '640x480']
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Sort them by what criterium exactly? Total number of pixels?

Comment: This appear to be `width*height` products. What do you want to sort the list by? By width? By height? By the surface `width*height`? By the ratio?

Comment: The usual sort and sorted didnt work out. So i just had a thought of just using the first value (Basically just use A eg: use 1920 from 1920X1080) in the AxB resolution of each element and sort that.

Comment: By width. basically i need the highest resolution from the list of resolutions.

Comment: Those are not the same thing '1440x1080' is a higher resolution than '1600x900', which would be higher if you went by width only.

Comment: @Aravindh, based on your comments, you have 2 relevant choices. either screen size, or a total number of pixels. As Grismar clarified above, using only width would be quite ambigous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TLDR;

My last approach seems to be the most relevant for your case. When you see a device that states "14-inch screen", they are talking about the diagonal and not the height or width. So, if you want to say that a MacBook 15 > MacBook 13 then thats the one to go for. If you purely want to work with resolution and pixels, then try the second last one which would be more relevant.

---

You can use `sorted()` along with a custom key with lambda function to extract height, width and apply your computation. You will also need `reverse=True` based on what you are trying to do.

The lambda function takes each element as `x` and then extracts the width and/or height using `x.split('x')[0]` and `x.split('x')[1]` respectively. Then you can choose to use Pythagoras theorem to get the diagonal OR just product them to get your pixels, etc..

I try to not use any external libraries such as numpy or math for this. Read more about the `sorted` function [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html).

#### Sorting by width only -

[image]

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x.split('x')[0]), reverse=True)
```

#### Sorting by height only -

[image]

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x.split('x')[1]), reverse=True)
```

#### Sorting by Aspect ratio (width/height) -

[image]

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x.split('x')[0])/int(x.split('x')[1]), reverse=True)
```

#### Sorting by the number of pixels (width*height) -

[image]

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x.split('x')[0])*int(x.split('x')[1]), reverse=True)
```

#### Sorting by monitor screen size (diagonal of the screen) -

> screen size = sqrt((width^2)+(height^2))

[image]

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: (int(x.split('x')[0])**2+int(x.split('x')[1])**2)**(1/2), reverse=True)
```

```
['1920x1080',
 '1600x900',
 '1280x1024',
 '1152x864',
 '1024x768',
 '800x600',
 '720x400',
 '640x480']
```

Comment: When sorting by diagonal length there is no need for `**(1/2)` in the key.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `key` parameter of [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
res = sorted(data, key=lambda x: [int(s) for s in x.split("x")], reverse=True)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['1920x1080', '1600x900', '1280x1024', '1152x864', '1024x768', '800x600', '720x400', '640x480']
```

This will break ties by height

Answer (score 1):

Use an appropriate sort metric that you can implement as a simple function and pass to `sort` as `key` parameter, e.g.:

```
def key(res):
    return (*map(int, s.split("x")))

resolutions.sort(key=key, reverse=True)
```

This will sort by width first, and height second. Or more generally:

```
def key(res):
    width, height = map(int, s.split("x"))
    result = # ... any numeric value calculated from the two
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted` with a custom function, here I am taking the product (i.e., total pixel size) of the two dimensions:

```
l = ['1152x864', '1920x1080', '1600x900', '1280x1024', '1024x768', '640x480', '720x400', '800x600']

from math import prod
sorted(l, key=lambda x: prod(map(int, x.split('x'))), reverse=True)
```

output:

```
['1920x1080',
 '1600x900',
 '1280x1024',
 '1152x864',
 '1024x768',
 '800x600',
 '640x480',
 '720x400']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide what criterium you want to sort with respect to.

```py
l = ['1152x864', '1920x1080', '1600x900', '1280x1024', '1024x768', '640x480', '720x400', '800x600']
```

By width:

```py
sorted(l, key=lambda dim: int(dim.split('x')[0]), reverse=True)
# ['1920x1080', '1600x900', '1280x1024', '1152x864', '1024x768', '800x600', '720x400', '640x480']
```

By height:

```py
sorted(l, key=lambda dim: int(dim.split('x')[1]), reverse=True)
# ['1920x1080', '1280x1024', '1600x900', '1152x864', '1024x768', '800x600', '640x480', '720x400']
```

By total number of pixels:

```py
from math import prod
sorted(l, key=lambda dim: prod(map(int, dim.split('x'))), reverse=True)
# ['1920x1080', '1600x900', '1280x1024', '1152x864', '1024x768', '800x600', '640x480', '720x400']
```

By length of diagonal:

```py
from math import hypot
sorted(l, key=lambda dim: hypot(*map(int, dim.split('x'))), reverse=True)
# ['1920x1080', '1600x900', '1280x1024', '1152x864', '1024x768', '800x600', '720x400', '640x480']
```

Relevant documentation:

- [Sorting How-To](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html);
- [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split);
- [math.prod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.prod);
- [math.hypot](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.hypot).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function it will do trick.

```
def orderByResolution(arr):
mytempdict = {}
result = []
for i in arr:
    mykey = int(i[:i.index('x')])
    mytempdict[mykey] = i

for i in reversed(sorted(mytempdict)):
    result.append(mytempdict[i])

return result
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to sort as you want to get your desired output you can try this:

```py
def bubbleSort(arr):
    arr = arr.copy()
    n = len(arr)
 
    # Traverse through all array elements
    for i in range(n-1):
    # range(n) also work but outer loop will repeat one time more than needed.
 
        # Last i elements are already in place
        for j in range(0, n-i-1):
 
            # traverse the array from 0 to n-i-1
            # Swap if the element found is greater
            # than the next element
            if int(arr[j].split("x")[0]) < int(arr[j + 1].split("x")[0]) :
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
    
    return arr

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inp_reso = ['1152x864', '1920x1080', '1600x900', '1280x1024', '1024x768', '640x480', '720x400', '800x600']
    print(bubbleSort(inp_reso))
```

but if you want to sort by number of total pixels in screen you must go with:

```py
def bubbleSort(arr):
    arr = arr.copy()
    n = len(arr)
 
    # Traverse through all array elements
    for i in range(n-1):
    # range(n) also work but outer loop will repeat one time more than needed.
 
        # Last i elements are already in place
        for j in range(0, n-i-1):
 
            # traverse the array from 0 to n-i-1
            # Swap if the element found is greater
            # than the next element
            if eval(arr[j].replace("x", "*")) < eval(arr[j + 1].replace("x", "*")) :
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
    
    return arr

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inp_reso = ['1152x864', '1920x1080', '1600x900', '1280x1024', '1024x768', '640x480', '720x400', '800x600']
    print(bubbleSort(inp_reso))
```

Comment: Not sure if re-implementing a sorting algorithm is really necessary ;)

Comment: i just wrote one of the possible solutions , i might help someone who is hoping to understand how does it works internally ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
l=['1152x864', '1920x1080', '1600x900', '1280x1024', '1024x768', '640x480', '720x400', '800x600']

for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i]=float(l[i].replace ('x','.'))

l.sort(reverse=True)

for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i]=str(l[i]).replace ('.','x')
print(l)
```